# Css isn't working on my meteor iOS app, but in Browser it work perfectly

Tags: ios, css, xcode, cordova, meteor

When I build and run my meteor app on my phone (iOS), the css isn't working, but when I access to my localhost on the browser there is no css problems... Have anyone an idea about the problem ? I build and run my app with Xcode.

Thanks for your answers !

If I try to modify the css file from the app in .meteor/local/cordova-build/www/application/app/client/main.scss, after building the app, all what I change disappears.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please add the code where you include the css in your app?

Comment: @Jankapunkt yes, I include it in the mains.js with an import with this code: import './main.scss';

Comment: The file you are hand modifying is a built file, and will be replaced on rebuild - no point in editing that. You also won't get the hot reload from editing that file